# Enable Wireless on Fresh Debian Build

Tags: debian, wifi

I have just installed Debian on a HP Envy laptop, with GNOME.

```
root@Cavalier:/home/jon# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l

root@Cavalier:/home/jon# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

I am connected to the internet using a cable. I would like to connect via wifi.

I have a broadcom wifi adapter installed:

```
root@Cavalier:/home/jon# lspci | grep Wireless
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

There is an icon in the top right that tells me that it the "Wired" status is "Connected". But I can't see anything similar for wireless.

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#GNOME), but after logging out or rebooting, I don't see anything related to wireless in the top right.

I have tried running nm-applet, but get an error:

root@Cavalier:/home/jon# nm-applet

```
(nm-applet:2663): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to initialize D-Bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

What else can I try to get the wifi working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

https://wiki.debian.org/wl

Comment: Thank you Ipor. How did you know that? Is it related to the proprietary drivers? I was previously on LUbuntu, which appeared to automatically detect the proprietary drivers on installation.

Comment: On ubuntu the driver is included in the kernel , On debian you need to add  the `non-free` repo

Comment: Does the process above install CPU and GPU drivers too?

Comment: you should get the info of your GPU and cpu , first , `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq` and `lspci | grep -i 'vga'`

Answer (score 2):

According to [deian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) you need to install the `broadcom-sta-dkms` packages then to load the `wl` driver

Add the `non-free` repository :

```
# Debian 8 "Jessie"
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Install `broadcom-sta-dkms` package and dependencies :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload conflicting drivers:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the `wl` module:

```
modprobe wl
```